# How do I knit output from print paste

Tags: r, r-markdown

The code below prompts a user to enter a number (in the console), then takes that number and returns a multiplication table. However when I knit to html, it shows "NA" (see screenshot). How do I show knit the multiplication table properly. Here is the code -

```
n <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number to return the multiplication table:"))

x <- c(1:12)
for(i in x){
print(paste(n,"x", i, "=", i*n))
}
```

[image]